# Updating Credit Card Payment

Tags: profile

I need to update my payment credit card information to CiviCRM. The card on file is expired and I cant figure out how to update.

Comment: Are you talking about a Spark subscription for CiviCRM perhaps? if so then suggest you email spark@civicrm.org

Answer (score 1):

Welcome Lisa!

Whether you can update your credit card information is dependent on the organization whose CiviCRM you're using.  Some payment processors (e.g. PayPal) allow updating expired credit cards. Others do not.

You are hopefully receiving an email each month confirming that your recurring payment went through.  If you have the ability to update your credit card information directly through CiviCRM, there should be a link toward the bottom of the email that you can click to update your card information.  If not, you should reach out directly to the organization.